# Non-visible declaration in specification file (.ads)

Tags: generics, package, ada

I keep getting the errors stated below. I have moved the offending record in and out of the private section of the package but the error presists. I am new to Ada and I am having issues implementing this generic stack to hold an array of records.

I have moved the record and type declarations in and out of the private section. I have also tried adding a "type garagebay is private" declaration before the private section as seen in the code.

```ada
-- .ads file --
generic
  low: integer; --lowerbound of stack
  up: integer; -- upperbound of stack
  type item is private; -- type of stack

package gstack is
  type garageBay is private;

  procedure tpush(x: in item);
  procedure tpop(x: out item);
private
  type vehicle is array(1..15) of character;
  type vName is array(1..8) of character;
  type garageBay is record
      vehicleType: vehicle;
      vehicleName: vName;
      time2Fix: integer;
      startTime: integer;
      finishTime: integer;
  end record;
  type entries is array(low..up) of item;
end gstack;
```

```ada
-- driver file
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;  -- in file Gusestac.adb
with gstack;  -- generic stack defined in gstack10.ads /.adb
procedure gusestack is
    package IIO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(integer); use IIO;
    lowerbound: integer;
    upperbound: integer;
begin
    get(lowerbound);
    get(upperbound);
    declare
      package genericS is new gstack(lowerbound,upperbound, garageBay);
      use genericS;
    begin
      put(""); -- placeholder
    end;
end gusestack;
```

```
-- Errors
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-8 -c gusestack.adb
gusestack.adb:11:63: "garageBay" is not visible
gusestack.adb:11:63: non-visible declaration at gstack.ads:7
gusestack.adb:11:63: instantiation abandoned
gusestack.adb:12:13: "genericS" is undefined
gnatmake: "gusestack.adb" compilation Error
```

Comment: @SimonWright@DeeDee I have tried to update the record and push it into the stack with ;                                            put("Enter vehicle name: " ); 
get(garageBay.vehicleName); 
tpush(garageBay); and I get the error                                                                  "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-8 -c gusestack.adb.
gusestack.adb:24:21: invalid prefix in selected component "garageBay".
gusestack.adb:25:23: invalid use of subtype mark in expression or call.
gnatmake: "gusestack.adb" compilation error.

Comment: You seem to think that Garagebay is directly visible. It isn't. Understanding visibility is essential to understanding Ada, so I suggest you learn Ada's visibility rules before trying to go any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use the type `garageBay`, defined in the generic package `gstack`, to create a concrete instance of `gstack`. You may want to move the type definition `garageBay` from the private section of `gstack` into the declarative part of `gusestack`, before the instantiation of `gstack`.

Comment: Indeed: `gstack` is a generic stack of `item`s, and you want to instantiate `gstack` with `item => garageBay` - just as if I wanted to instantiate it with `item => coffeeBrand`, for instance.